# VLC Remote Access Hide

Tags: vlc, remote-access

How can I configure VLC so that the host doesn't appear when searching for hosts from app like Remote VLC?
Unfortunately I can't get a static IP for my Android phone so I can't restrict the access to one ip, but would like at least not to show up on other devices on the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably Zeroconf DNS-SD (Service Discovery) that the other apps are using to discover VLC. In Ubuntu, this service is provided by avahi-daemon.

If you don't want to advertise any services at all on the local network, you can just remove avahi-daemon. Avahi isn't necessary - clients wanting to access your services can still do so when the service IP and port number are provided manually.

```
sudo apt-get remove avahi-daemon
```

If you want to leave Avahi advertising some services but not VLC, look in /etc/avahi/services/ for a file relating to VLC. I don't have both installed on my machine, but assuming it has a name like vlc.service, something like this might work:

```
sudo mv /etc/avahi/services/vlc.service /etc/avahi/services/vlc.service.disabled
sudo restart avahi-daemon
```